# If I just want to use current version of files, do I still need the objects under .git/lfs?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, git-lfs

Use an example to explain.

I use these commands to download bart-large from huggingface:

```
git lfs install
git clone https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large
```

The downloaded folder bart-large has size of 11 GB. The size of .git/lfs alone is 5.2 GB.

I remove the objects under .git/lfs and still can load the models from the local bart-large folder. This makes me wonder if I just want to use the current version of models and will not modify the repo, do I still need objects under .git/lfs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not just delete files from under `.git/lfs`.  If you want to prune all unpushed objects, including those in the working tree, you can use `git lfs prune --force` to do so, which will free those objects.  On some systems, you can de-duplicate the files in the working tree with `git lfs dedup` instead of using `git lfs prune --force`; whether that works depends on your operating system and file system.  (It works on macOS with APFS, Windows with ReFS, and Linux with XFS and BTRFS, possibly among others.)  You can try it and it will inform you whether de-duplication is possible.

Note that `git lfs prune --force` does not delete unpushed objects, since they're not on the server; doing so would cause data loss, which is why you shouldn't just delete files from under `.git/lfs`, since that does, too.

Comment: What are the objects stored under .git/lfs? Are they old versions of models and files?

Comment: They are large files (e.g., models) downloaded with Git LFS.  Git LFS caches them in case you'd like to check out other revisions without needing to download the files again.

Comment: That is exactly my question. The current version/branch's model files are in the downloaded repo folder. If I don't need other/previous version/branch's models, then I can safely delete the objects in .git/lfs to save the disk space. Is this correct?

Comment: You should never just delete files in `.git/lfs`.  You should use the tools specified because they don't cause data loss, and will delete the data you don't want to keep without deleting data that isn't safe to delete.  Nothing under `.git/lfs` is ever safe to modify by hand.